# How do I remove dots from interactive guideline (but keep the tooltip)?

Tags: nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

The interactive guideline adds circles that move along each series as you mouse over the graph. However, if there are points in the graph that are undefined that dot just moves along the line the top of the graph. I want to remove these dots, preferably just when values are undefined, but if that's not possible then just remove them altogether. I tried just excluding the values that would be undefined in the time series, but that's also ugly, as the tooltip then shows the value in the series which is closest to your current position; I need it not to show a number if there isn't actually a value at that position.

Comment: I have the same problem - Have you found a solution ?

Comment: I don't feel like it's generic, but I added this to my css;`.nv-scatterWrap {display:none;}` and that hides them altogether, rather than just for undefined values.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks !